# Error #1063 with removeEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making a game in AS3.

I've got in my main class this function :

```
public function tire(e:MouseEvent):void{
                puzzle.removeListeners();
        }
```

And in my Puzzle class that :

```
 public function removeListeners():void{
        var cocoUn;
        var cocoDeux;
            var cocoTrois;
            var cocoQuatre;
        var cocoCinq;
  for (var i in Engine.usableItems){ // Ditto
            if (Engine.usableItems[i].displayName == "COCOUN")
            cocoUn = Engine.usableItems[i];
            if (Engine.usableItems[i].displayName == "COCODEUX")
            cocoDeux = Engine.usableItems[i];
            if (Engine.usableItems[i].displayName == "COCOTROIS")
            cocoTrois = Engine.usableItems[i];
            if (Engine.usableItems[i].displayName == "COCOQUATRE")
                cocoQuatre = Engine.usableItems[i];
            if (Engine.usableItems[i].displayName == "COCOCINQ")
                cocoCinq = Engine.usableItems[i];
                    }

        cocoUn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot, false, 0, true);
        cocoDeux.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootDeux, false, 0, true);
    cocoTrois.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootTrois, false, 0, true);
    cocoQuatre.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootQuatre, false, 0, true);
    cocoCinq.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shootCinq, false, 0, true);

      }
```

I want my 5 items to be unclickable when the function "tire" is called in my main class.

I've got an error in debug mode. 
When I click on the stage, this error appear : `Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on flash.events::EventDispatcher/removeEventListener(). Expected 2, got 5.`

Do you know how I can correct that ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method removeEventListener has only three arguments:

```
function removeEventListener(type:String,listener:Function,useCapture:Boolean = false):void
```

It should be enough to ajdust your code in the following way:

```
cocoUn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shoot);
```